# Akka supervisor on stop of subordinate

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using Akka 2.3.11 and [SupervisorStrategies](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html) for handling failures in the actors subordinates. However in addition to the supervision strategy I want to catch all "stops" (planned stops and such one which occur because of exceptions) of a subordinate to persist some information in the backends database.

How can I catch all stops of the subordinates in the supervisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `watch` any actor and receive a `Terminated` message whenever that actor stops.

To watch an actor user:

```
context.watch(actorRef)
```

and receive `Terminated` message just like any other message and do whatever backend jobs that you need there.